# Jest Snapshot failing because of Next.js JSX always rerendering w/ diff values

Tags: jestjs, next.js

This issues arises when I try to commit. I have a hook that runs tests. And the JSX in the next.js app (version 12+, so no babel config) constantly re-renders thus always creating a different snapshot because of the JSX difference.

```
            <i
                class="icon-large ht-icon ht-Arrow"
                data-testid="back-arrow"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
-           class="jsx-1237563464 touchTarget small"
+           class="jsx-1632859351 touchTarget small"
```

The problem is that, I update the snapshots "jest -u", then it all passes. BUT then I commit, runs the tests again, and now they are different and it errors, as shown above.

The solutions are to update babel, but with Next.js version 12, we no longer use a babel config.

So, how to solve this jsx noise???

Comment: What is generating the `jsx-*` class names?

Comment: @juliomalves next.js does that on its own.

Comment: Next.js wouldn't add it on its own. Are you using any CSS-in-JS tool, like stlyed-components or styled-jsx? Can you share the source code that generates that HTML output?

Comment: Next is for sure adding it - its their own css in js solutions, ala:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#css-in-js

Comment: Could you provide the source code and the test code please?